# Monte carlo estimation, but function value can only be estimated indirectly

Tags: conditional-expectation, variance, estimation, monte-carlo

I have the following setup.

I want to Monte Carlo estimate a big sum $$F=\sum_x p(x) f(x)$$ by drawing $\\{ x_1,\dots, x_M \\}$ from the distribution $p(x)$ and averaging $f(x_i)$.
However, in my case $$f(x) = G( \alpha(x))$$ where $\alpha(x) \in [-1,1]$ and $G$ is a known bounded but non-linear function $ 0 \leq G(a)\leq 1$ for $a\in [-1,1]$.

The issue is that I cannot compute $\alpha(x)$ exactly for a given $x$. Instead, I can only estimate these quantities $\alpha(x)$ from a finite number of samples. To be more precise, for a given $x$ and corresponding $\alpha(x)$, I will draw $K$ Bernoulli random variables $A^{(x)}_1,\dots, A^{(x)}_K$ with $A^{(x)}_i \in \\{ -1, +1 \\}$ from a distribution such that $\mathbb{E} A^{(x)}_i = \alpha(x)$ to estimate $\alpha(x)$ via

$$\hat{\alpha}(x) = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{j=1}^K A^{(x)}_j$$

Hence, my final estimator is given by

\begin{align}
\hat{F} &= \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i=1}^M G \left( \hat{\alpha}(x) \right) \\\\
 &= \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i=1}^M G \left(\frac{1}{K}\sum_{j=1}^K A^{(x)}_j  \right)
\end{align}

My question is:

1. Is $\hat{F}$ even an unbiased estimator of $F$? given that $G$ is non-linear, it doesnt seem like it?
2. Say I wanted to show that with high probability $|\hat{F} - F| <\epsilon$ when drawing enough samples, i.e. choosing $K$ and $M$ large enough. How would you approach this? Can we control the variance of $\hat{F}$?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that, in general, $\hat{F}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $F$ because of the non-linearity of $G$. Here's an example.

Suppose $\alpha(x) = 0$ and $G(a) = a^2$. (Note that this means your Bernoulli distributions have $50\%$ chance of $-1$ and $50\%$ chance of $1$.) Then $F = 0$. But $\hat{\alpha}(x)$ is

- $0$ if your Bernoulli samples balance out exactly (i.e. half are $-1$ and half are $1$),
- positive otherwise.

This means that $\hat{F}$ has positive expectation, and is therefore biased.

---

For the second part of your question I don't have an answer that completely solves the whole thing, but I think it's important to understand that $\hat{F}$ being close to $F$ is *not* the same as the variance of $\hat{F}$ being small, exactly because of the bias.
In order for $\hat{F}$ to approximate $F$ well, you need both its variance and its bias to be small.
This observation is usually called [the bias-variance decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Bias%E2%80%93variance_decomposition_of_mean_squared_error).

Assuming you have lots of samples of $\hat{F}$, you can estimate the variance [the usual way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) (i.e. just check whether they're close together). That leaves you with the problem of understanding how big the bias is. This will require some assumptions on $G$, but for a reasonably nice $G$ the bias will shrink to zero as $K\to\infty$.
Assuming $G$ is smooth enough and $K$ is big enough that $\hat{\alpha}$ is very concentrated near $\alpha$, the bias will be about proportional to the second derivative of $G$ at $\alpha$. So whether $G$ is *very* non-linear or just a bit non-linear will dictate whether the bias is large.

To gain intuition about why the second derivative of $G$ dictates the bias, you could work out the bias of $\hat{F}$ exactly for the example above (in which case the math works out immediately, because $G$ is equal to its second order Taylor approximation). Then try replacing $G$ with a general quadratic polynomial and repeat the exercise.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers. I will try to reconcile this with the analysis provided in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

About the second question, you can use Hoeffding's inequality twice. From this inequality, using $K=\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}\log \frac{2}{\delta}$ samples,

\begin{equation}
     \mathbb{P}\left( |\hat{\alpha}(x)-\alpha(x)|\geq \epsilon\right)\leq \delta
\end{equation}

Next, assuming that the function $G$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $L$ (In case the function is not Lipschitz continuous, you can try other types of continuities, for instance checking if the function is Hölder continuous). Therefore, for any set of $M$ points $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^M$,

\begin{equation}
    \left|\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M G(\alpha(x_i))- \frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M G(\hat{\alpha}(x_i))\right|\leq L \epsilon
\end{equation}

with probability at least $1-M\delta$. This follows from the union bound. Similarly, using Hoeffding's inequality,

\begin{equation}
     \mathbb{P}\left( \left|\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M G(\alpha(x_i))-\mathbb{E}[G(\alpha(x))]\right|\geq \epsilon_2\right)\leq \delta_2
\end{equation}

where $M=\frac{1}{2\epsilon_2^2} \log \frac{2}{\delta_2}$. Finally, combining both results,

\begin{equation}
     \left|\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M G(\hat{\alpha}(x_i))-\mathbb{E}[G(\alpha(x))]\right|\leq \epsilon_2+L \epsilon
\end{equation}

with probability at least $1-\delta M -\delta_2$. For example, you can take $\delta_2=\delta_0/2$, $\delta=\delta_0/2M$, $\epsilon_2=\epsilon_0/2$, and $\epsilon=\epsilon_0/(2L)$, yielding

\begin{equation}
     \left|\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M G(\hat{\alpha}(x_i))-\mathbb{E}[G(\alpha(x))]\right|\leq \epsilon_0
\end{equation}

with probability at least $1-\delta_0$, where $M=\frac{2}{\epsilon_0^2}\log \frac{4}{\delta_0}$, and $K=\frac{8L^2}{\epsilon_0^2} \log \frac{4M}{\delta_0}$.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is precisely what I was looking for.